# Upload file, check for same file name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

Hi i'am using this utils, to make file upload and delete upload. MVC 4 LINQ to SQL.

I would like to check if file is already uploaded, and if, make a meassage
to try new file.

Can you help me, getting started, to add code for this ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;


namespace CFire2.SupplyConUtils

{
public static class FileUpload
{

    public static char DirSeparator =
    System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    public static string FilesPath = "Content" +
    DirSeparator + "SupplyUpload" + DirSeparator;

    public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Check if we have a file
        if (null == file) return "";
        // Make sure the file has content
        if (!(file.ContentLength > 0)) return "";

        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        // Make sure we were able to determine a proper
        // extension
        if (null == fileExt) return "";

        // Check if the directory we are saving to exists
        if (!Directory.Exists(FilesPath))
        {
            // If it doesn't exist, create the directory
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilesPath);
        }

        //// Set our full path for saving
        var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/SupplyUpload"), fileName);


        // Save our file


        file.SaveAs(path);

        // Return the filename
        return fileName;


    }
    public static void DeleteFile(string fileName)
    {
        // Don't do anything if there is no name
        if (fileName.Length == 0) return;

        // Set our full path for deleting
        var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/SupplyUpload"), fileName);


        // Check if our file exists

          if (File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // Delete our file

            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN docs for [HttpPostedFileBase.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> When overridden in a derived class, gets the fully qualified name of
>   the file on the client.

So probably you need to add this line to correctly execute your check

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

and then

```
   var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/SupplyUpload"), 
                                                              fileName);
   if(File.Exists(path))
       return "The file has been already uploaded!
   ....
```

Comment: Hej Steve   Works perfect   tks.